# DateFormater gives day before swift

Tags: swift, date, dateformatter

when I use DateFormateer it returns me a day before.

```
nextDayShouldBe = currectDay.addingTimeInterval(24 * 3600)
print(nextDayShouldBe) //prints (2022-07-02 21:58:11 +0000) it's right
        
let nextDay = nextDayShouldBe?.getFormattedDate(format: format)
try? realm.write({
    userData?.nextDay = nextDay
    print(nextDayShouldBe?.getFormattedDate(format: format)) // prints "01/07/2022"
})
```

I tried all methods to fix it (dateformatter.locale, timeZone, calendar).

```
extension Date {
   func getFormattedDate(format: String) -> String {
        let dateformat = DateFormatter()
        dateformat.dateFormat = format
        dateformat.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 10800)
       dateformat.calendar = .current
       dateformat.locale = Locale.autoupdatingCurrent
    
       return dateformat.string(from: self)
    }
}
```

How to get  2022-07-02 ??

Comment: First tip: do not use "addingTimeInterval" method to get the next day. Use `Calendar` for that. You almost never need to calculate dates without a calendar.

Answer (score 0):

okey, I did it and it works:

```
nextDayShouldBe = currectDay.addingTimeInterval(24 * 3600)
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
let fromDateToString = dateFormatter.string(from: nextDayShouldBe!)
print(fromDateToString)
```